# Delaying Data Source methods after remote images are downloaded

Tags: arrays, swift, model-view-controller, koloda

I'm using this library https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda 
Basically this is a pod that helps me implement a Tinder-like swiping interface.

This pod has a Data Source method called `kolodaNumberOfCards(_ koloda: KolodaView)` which requires you to declare **how many cards** the program is expecting to show in the Koloda View.

```
func kolodaNumberOfCards(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> Int {
        return allCards.list.count
}
```

I am implementing a MVC architecture in my app so I have a Data Model class file which I instantiate at the top of this current view controller.

```
var allCards = QuestionBank()
```

In `QuestionBank` class, I have a **list** (array) of `Card` objects which contains all the metadata of the `Card` objects. `Card` object also contains the UIImage I want to instantiate in the KolodaCard View.

PROBLEM COMES when I do not have the Card objects in the QuestionBank list array at init! These `Card` objects are appended to the list after I fetch data **remotely** from an API.

However, in my ViewController containing the KolodaView, I need to declare **how many cards** the program is expecting to show in the Koloda View. Since **list.count** is 0 when you first enter the ViewController, the KolodaView would thus expect 0 card!

Currently my KolodaView is not showing any of my downloaded images.

Is there a way to delay the Data Source methods by Koloda so that the program can wait for all the data to be fetched from API or is there another solution around this problem?

Comment: No need to delay. After you get the remote data and update your data model, call whatever API the view provides to reload it (similar to `UITableView reloadData`.

Comment: what about the kolodaNumberOfCards part where I need to declare how many cards are there but at the start there is no element in the list so the program assume there is going to be 0 card in the Koloda View?

Comment: Let it start out at 0. Once the data is updated and you reload the data, it will return the updated number.